# Can we call API in Policy center

Tags: api, rest, guidewire

I have Policy Center V10.0.3 installed. I have a remote service deployed wants to call PC to run Quote generation.

Is it possible to call Policy Center function such ask Policy Quote calculation using REST API?

Comment: Hi Luke. You must search in documentation. In 8.0.4 doesn't exist an API for that but I dont know 10.03 version.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosDuque

Answer (score 0):

You can use SOAPUI.
Fetch the wsdl from PC web services in SOAP UI and create a mock request.
You can call any functions exposed in Policy Center.